# Pagination on with mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a system that automatically paginates all mysql queries with LIMIT and OFFSET.

Example:

```
// Page 1
SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE category_id = 1 LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

// Page 2
SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE category_id = 1 LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20

// Page 3
SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE category_id = 1 LIMIT 20 OFFSET 40

etc.
```

Now the questions itself.

A) Is this the best way to do it? Are there any alternatives?

B) When I land on a product page (products.php?id=12345) and there will be a list of products on the same page, how can I choose the correct page on the product list? If this product happens to be on the 105th page on the product list?

This is to highlight the "selected product" on the list. Now it only works if the product happens to be on the first page, which is always automatically loaded to the products.php page.

Comment: First of all, you must always include an `order by` clause if you have `limit` clause. Otherwise the pages won't be consistent.

Comment: Well since this all pseudo here I skipped it. It will still be consistent as it's sorted by id or chronologically by default.

Answer (score 2):

For example if your first page has a get variable in the url www.tst.com?page=1

```
off = (page - 1)*20 ;
row = 20;
select * from table limit (off, row);
```

optimally you would use something like this. The code is much faster than two queries where you would have to do a count on the table and then use that count result as your new parameters because of the potential for n amount of rows in your table... The larger the table the less efficient queries will be.

Answer (score 1):

> A) Is this the best way to do it? Is there any alternatives?

It probably is the best way as pagination is performed by the server and only the desired rows are returned.

> B) [...] how can I choose the correct page on the product list [...]

I can think of two possible solutions:

---

In your detail pages use a query that selects all ids:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM tbl_products
WHERE category_id = 1
ORDER BY id
```

Note the `ORDER BY` clause... both queries (the one with `LIMIT` and the one that selects all ids) must be ordered in exactly the same way. You can then loop through all rows using PHP code and locate the index at which the product id exists. Then divide this number by the page size to determine the page number.

---

An alternate solution is to se a MySQL query that numbers the rows such as the following:

```
SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS row_number, id
FROM tbl_products, (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS temp1
WHERE category_id = 1
ORDER BY id
```

Nest this query inside another query to determine the row number of the specific id:

```sql
SELECT row_number FROM (
    SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS row_number, id
    FROM tbl_products, (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS temp1
    WHERE category_id = 1
    ORDER BY id
) AS temp2 WHERE id = 1234
```

Divide the row number by page size to get page number.

Comment: The first thing is pretty much what I am doing but it seems like an awful idea to do a full table scan on everytime I load the page just to figure out the correct page number. :/

Comment: If you select only the id the database should be able to use an index.